# Minecraft Plugin loading but command is unkown

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have been creating a plugin for Minecraft on Eclipse, but I am encountering an error. The plugin loads fine; I can see it in the console, but it says unknown command when I try and run the command.

Here is my command code:

```
package me.TheThunder56.helloworld.commands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.TheThunder56.helloworld.Main;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class HelloCommand implements CommandExecutor{

    private Main plugin;
    
    public HelloCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("sword").setExecutor(this);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("Only players may execute this command!");
            return true;
        }
        
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        
        if(p.hasPermission("sword.use")) {
            p.performCommand("/give TheThunder56 netherite_sword{Unbreakable:1,Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:1000}]}");
            return true;
        }else {
            p.sendMessage("You do not have permission to execute this command.");
            
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my Main.java:

```
package me.TheThunder56.helloworld;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.TheThunder56.helloworld.commands.HelloCommand;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getCommand("sword").setExecutor(new HelloCommand(this));
    }
}
```

And here is my plugin.yml file:

```
name: GodSword
main: me.TheThunder56.helloworld.Main
version: 1.0
author: TheThunder56
commands:
  sword:
    description: A command to give you a godly sword.
    usage: /sword
```

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Main plugin;
    
    public HelloCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("sword").setExecutor(this);

 

    public void onEnable() {
        getCommand("sword").setExecutor(new HelloCommand(this));
    }
```

Why are you registering your command twice? No need. Only register the command in your onenable. Also, for your method to give the player the sword, you should not use p.performCommand();, because even if they have the permission they still need op to use /give.

Try using this:

```
ItemStack sword = new ItemStack(Material.NETHERITE_SWORD));
ItemMeta meta = sword.getItemMeta();
meta.addUnsafeEnchantment(Enchantment.KNOCKBACK, 1000, true);
meta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_UNBREAKABLE);
meta.setUnbreakable(true);
meta.setCustomName(ChatColor.GOLD + "GOD Sword"));
sword.setItemMeta(meta);

int i = 0;

while(true){
   for(ItemStack it = p.getInventory(){
        if(it == null){
            p.getInventory().setItem(i, sword);
            break;
        }else{
           i++;
        }
    }
}
```